# Make div's height lower if it meets another content

Tags: javascript, css

I'm working on a timeline and I want to represent any event on the timeline as a line with a description next to it. However if 2 lines are too close so their contents collide I want one of the lines to be shorter. Here is an example:

```
|note number 1                          |This line is the same height as the
| |this line is lower                   |first one
| |so it doesn't hit the text above it  |
| |                                     |
| |                                     |
| |                                     |
```

Thanks!

Comment: You just need to put the lower line in the flow below the upper line. It goes from top to bottom. So it automatically pushes down.

Comment: @AjAX thanks for your response. I don't understand what you mean by "put the lower line in the flow below the upper line"... Can you demonstrate with a quick code example?

Comment: With flow I meant the usually used term for that in `CSS`. As in “`position:absolute` takes out of the flow”.

Comment: @AjAX.
I'm sorry I still not quit sure what your proposal is... As of now here is the CSS settings for the line(=event):
    position: absolute;
    height:100px;

Comment: As I said. If possible get rid of the `position:absolute`. So the `div` stays in the flow. And keep the `height` for `note number 1` on `auto`. Do `padding`.

Comment: @AjAX.
I have to set position:absolute (so I can position the line on the timeline which is it's ancestor).

Comment: Can you set up a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Quick code examples.

```css
.lower{
    margin-left:25px;
    background:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="upper"></div>

<div class="lower">This is the lower.</div>
```

```css
.lower{
    margin-left:25px;
    background:blue;
}

.upper{
    background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="upper">This is the upper with text.</div>

<div class="lower">This is the lower.</div>
```

Comment: That's not what I meant. I want the lower line to cut short only in case it collide with an upper content. You simply add margin...

Comment: You can do without margin. But this is how I read your example. Where are you stuck exactly?